# Can I get Rails debugging output in Pow similar to WEBrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, webrick, rack-pow

When I use rails/server (WEBrick) I get constant debug info (queries, etc) from my rails app as console output. Is there a way to get this debug output with Pow?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check the HTTP requests that Pow receives by running `tail -f` on the log file of your choice in the `~/Library/Logs/Pow` directory. Check out the Pow manual section on [Viewing Log Files](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.6)

If you're looking for Rails specific logs, they'll be located in the `log/` directory of your application. For instance, if you want to watch the development log for your application switch to the root director of the application and run:

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

There's also `less` which will give you a few more options, but isn't quite as simple to use.

```
less -R log/development.log
```

and then press `ctrl-f` to follow new output to the file. Pressing `h` will give you a more detailed help menu.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a helper gem like [powder](https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder). I order to show application log just type `powder applog`

Comment: It would be great to have `binding.pry` accessible from there.

Comment: This is the best answer. `powder` is more than just tailing the log, it gives you the equivalent of the real-time `rails server` display after the initial tail.  This is about as similar to Webrick or Thin as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see a `log/development.log` path in your application? You can typically use that to see what is taking place within Rails. There are also logs for testing and production as well and they might be present for your project depending on the mode that the application is running in.

To access these logs you should use the Terminal and `cd` to your application, you can then use a utility such as `tail` to see the logs. A variation of the tail command would also scroll the output when there is new content like the Rails logger normally does.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pry-remote gem.
References:
https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote
https://coderwall.com/p/sreazq